# Chat service and persistance

Tags: java, concurrency, playframework-2.0, webserver, akka

I'm planning to write a a simple 1-1 chat service. I've chose to use the Play! framework (Java web framework).
Let's assume a chat server is serving two users and suddenly the server crahses.

Is it something I need to take into account?
How often is it expected to happen? (On average for a chat server).

**And the most important question:**
How to handle this kind of situation? Technically, both users should be transfered seamlessly to another node on the cloud + I want to **save the state of both users and other information which relevant for the chat session**

Footnote:

- I heard about a tool called Akka but at a first glance, it looks like an heavy tool which shall be learned deeply.
- I hope my question doesn't fall under "Broad Question". I think it's pretty much specific and concrente.

Comment: Actually Akka is not so heavy tool, also Play is built on top of Akka, so it might be a good idea to check it. Akka has module named [Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/persistence.html), you can use it to keep all messages and other related info as events. Akka Persistence keeps these events in memory, but you can also have backend storage, so it should be relatively easy to restore chat sessions from it (even in case of crash).

Comment: Thanks! Can you briefly explain how Akka can handle the scenerio I described in my question? (Server crash while a chat session)

Comment: Sure, Akka Persistence saves all events to journal. You can use different SQL and NoSQL databases as journals, for example Cassandra or MongoDB (it's all done with Akka Persistence plugins).
After restart it reads journal and builds latest state from it.

Comment: I'm curious, If Akka wan't an option (for example, if I used PHP, Rails, etc). What would be an alternative solution?

Comment: Well, principle is very simple - save your state to persistent storage (any database) as a history and then restore it by request (for example using some session id). I suggest you to read these articles: [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), [EventSourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka has a great Clustering support, what you describe seems like a good use case for [Akka Cluster Singleton](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/contrib/cluster-singleton.html#cluster-singleton). Akka will make sure that an instance of the chat server will always be running in your cluster. If you want to persist the state of the users you will need to use Akka Persistence as well, ideally using a distributed journal in the backend.

In my experience Akka is very easy and fun to work with, but there is a certain learning curve you need to tackle first.

As you want to use Play using Akka makes sense, as Play is build on Akka, so integrating will be pretty seamless and you will have Akka in your project already.